# What is the "facility of a question"?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

The phrase is commonly used [in mark schemes](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22facility%20of%20the%20question%22), like so:

> The *facility* of the question was 65%,

Facility is defined as..."bathroom", "service", or "absence of difficulty" in [Lexico.](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/facility)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***facility*** often indicates:

> ease of doing or making; absence of difficulty

[Collins online](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/facility)

In this case, it is [a statistical term relating to test and survey items](https://www.csusm.edu/iits/services/ats/idesign/cougarcourses/guides/quiz-results-and-statistics/index.html) and their relative ease of being answered correctly. It usually equals the [*mean*.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean)

[image]

[chart: moodle.org](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Quiz_report_statistics)

It is sometimes referred to as "item difficulty". When the index is too low, it might indicate that the test was bad, and should be discarded.
On the other hand, this metric can be (ab)used by teachers to adjust overall performance of a group by skewing tests to raise the class average.